# Google Apps Script HtmlService nested createHtmlOutputFromFile to create JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, google-apps-script

I am pretty new to this.

I created a JQuery WebApp with Google Apps Script and it's all new and exciting for me.
The past days I read and learn a lot, try to get things together.

My starting point has been some examples and took parts from here and there, finally got it running.

But there are a lot of questions, my biggest one is hot to structure the HTML stuff.

The app uses different JQuery Pages and a Navigation bar to change/visit them.
My first idea was to code the navigation bar just once and include it dynamically at the needed positions. But I can't get it working.

This is what I got:

Code.gs

```
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('myAPP')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

Index.html

```
  <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">

  <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<!-- Store data passed to template here, so it is available to the
     imported JavaScript. -->
<script>
  var access_token = <?= access_token ?>;
</script>



<!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Script').getContent(); ?>
```

Script.html

Inside here is all the JQuery code I use.
At he point I want to include the Navbars, i try the same the above:

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Navbar').getContent(); ?>
```

But it does not work. I also tried to include it into `<script> ... </script>`

I really don't understand why it works for the first time, but not for the second, nested time.

===== EDIT - HERE IS MY DEMO ====

https://script.google.com/d/1jwKy9OJp5jD95NkaAwLFTs0LPSxlP9eW2iWdNXuizfFxaKGw-iWZBV3z/edit?usp=sharing

You can see the point where I want to 'include' the Navbar at line 5 in JQuery.html.

=====
Cheers,

Heiko

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using this:

### Index.html

```
<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">

<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<!-- Store data passed to template here, so it is available to the
 imported JavaScript. -->

<?!= include('JQuery'); ?>
<?!= include('Navbar'); ?>
```

### code.gs

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But i cant get it woking in no way. I set up a complete demo which shows the whole code. Please take a look at my initial post which i have edited.

Comment: Sorry, no, this is not working. Your answer is not matching my question because i need the include inside the JQuery.html and not in only in Index.html. Please take a look at my Demo. I want to use the Navbar at different places inside the JQuery.html. Simply because i want to have only one source for all Navbars in all JQuery pages. First implementation in line 5. Doesent work. :-(

Comment: Any CSS, or Script that is included in the index.html is available to the entire application.

Comment: Thanks for that information! But it doesnt change that fact that i cant use my Navbar inside the JQuery.html as I wish. :-( I might be stupid and for sure an all beginner in this stuff, but would you help me with the syntax and writing?

Comment: No, I won't make a commitment to do anything for you.  Any help that is received or given on the site is completely voluntary.  I might never look at this post again, I might suddenly feel like doing more, and keep trying.  You just need to manage your expectations.